# WPF Slider control (NullReferenceException)

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to display the value of a slider control in a TextBlock. However I keep getting a NullRerferenceException when I try to load the dialog.

```
public partial class GeneralSettingsDialog : Window
{

    public GeneralSettingsDialog()
    {  
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DistSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        DistTextBlock.Text = DistSlider.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
        <TabItem Header="Miscellaneous" Name="tabItem1" Background="#FFF0F0F0">
            <Grid Height="230" Background="#FFF0F0F0">
                <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,13,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="Spacing" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <Slider Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" TickPlacement="BottomRight" Margin="13,35,0,0" Name="DistSlider" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Interval="1" Maximum="50" Minimum="1" ValueChanged="DistSlider_ValueChanged" />
                <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="111,35,0,0" Name="DistTextBlock" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
```

Comment: try to debug and check if the object DistSlider.Value is null or not.

Comment: It appears the problem is with the textblock, since the value displays ok in a messagebox.

Comment: please show your XAML, no crystal balls here. :)

Comment: Try x:Name instead of Name when naming your elements.

Comment: @dowhilefor, just tried that but still getting the same exception.

Comment: DistSlider_ValueChanged gets triggered when the dialog is loaded, so could it be that the text block is being assigned value before it had a chance to initialize properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly sure why your way isn't working, I guess the controls are not fully initialized when the first value changed event is thrown. But you can do it that way directly in xaml without any code behind:

in TextBlock bind directly to the slider's current value and remove the value changed event handler:

```
 Text="{Binding ElementName=DistSlider, Path=Value}"
```

PS:

When you attach to the slider's value changed event in codebehind after InitializeComponent() your  approach should also work fine:

```
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  DistSlider.ValueChanged +=new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<double>(DistSlider_ValueChanged);
}

private void DistSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    DistTextBlock.Text = DistSlider.Value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your XAML you have the `TextBlock` *DistTextBlock* defined **after** *DistSlider*. When the XAML is loaded for the first time it will fire the `ValueChanged` handler and *DistTextBlock* will be null. You can protect against this in a few ways:

```
// 1. Naive, but least changes to your code
if (DistTextBlock != null)
{
    DistTextBlock.Text = DistSlider.Value.ToString();
}
```

There is [@SvenG's excellent suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611130/wpf-slider-control-nullreferenceexception/7611529#7611529), which moves the logic to the XAML (no need for a `ValueChanged` handler):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=DistSlider}" ... />
```

Lastly you could use a [`ViewModel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) (or any [data context supporting `INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)) to handle the passing to and from of the value.

The important part of using the binding is it allows you to put any [string formatting right alongside its usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) in the XAML (say, if this slider was for a currency amount):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=DistSlider, StringFormat={}{0:C}}"
```

The last bonus of using a binding is coming out in [.Net Framework 4.5, which allows you to specify a time delay prior to the binding updating its source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.delay%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This would allow your GUI to seem more reactive if the binding is used in expensive operations.

```
<Slider Value="{Binding DollarAmount, Delay=50}" ... />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DollarAmount, StringFormat={}{0:C}}" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. 
The Delay Binding property sounds really helpful, will definitely try that out with 4.5 .. thanks for mentioning that !

Comment: @SvenG: you're welcome, I was hoping he'd choose yours as it was the first to be correct; down with event handlers! I recommend reading the [.Net Framework 4.5 WPF changelog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more to look forward to.