# How to set a TextBox's Width programatically or from a slider

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am trying to edit a `TextBox` Width property programatically in C#, but eventually the best behaviour should be that the value should be defaulted when opening the app to 1000 then modified by using a `Slider`.

This is the code I'm using to set the Data Binding for the `Width` property.

```
<TextBox x:Name="MainTextArea"
         Margin="0,71" 
         BorderThickness="0" 
         Background="{x:Null}" 
         BorderBrush="{x:Null}"        
         SelectionHighlightColor="#FF444444" 
         Foreground="White" 
         Canvas.ZIndex="1"
         TabIndex="1" 
         Padding="0" 
         FontSize="18" 
         FontFamily="Georgia" 
         IsSpellCheckEnabled="False" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
         RequestedTheme="Dark" 
         Width="{Binding TextAreaWidth}" 
         TextChanged="MainTextArea_TextChanged" 
         TextWrapping="Wrap"
         AcceptsReturn="True" 
         PlaceholderText=""
         />
```

And here is the code which I am using to try and bind the property. (Has been copied and modified from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758320.aspx)

```
public class MyWidth : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private FrameworkElement _width;

    // Declare the PropertyChanged event.
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Create the property that will be the source of the binding.
    public FrameworkElement width
    {
        get { return _width; }
        set
        {
            _width = value;
            // Call NotifyPropertyChanged when the source property 
            // is updated.
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TextAreaWidth");
        }
    }

    // NotifyPropertyChanged will fire the PropertyChanged event, 
    // passing the source property that is being updated.
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string WidthProperty)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(WidthProperty));
        }
    }
}
```

I am then trying to set it in the MainPage class.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    // Create an instance of the MyWidth class 
    // that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.
    MyWidth mywidth = new MyWidth();

    mywidth.width = new FrameworkElement;  // this line is not recognized, I suppose it is incomplete, but I don't know what to write there.
    MainTextArea.DataContext = mywidth;

    // Create the binding and associate it with the text box.
    Binding binding = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("TextAreaWidth") };
    MainTextArea.SetBinding(TextBox.WidthProperty, binding);
}
```

For the moment `mywidth.width = new FrameworkElement;` is not recognized as a valid line, I suppose it is incomplete, but I don't know what to write there. In the example a new SolidColorBrush was created and used to set the color to red, but I don't know how to use this in the Framework element example.

To use a slider I guess I will need to call one of these classes in the Slider's `ValueChanged` Event.

Help?

### EDIT & Alternate Solution

@BryanStump's Answer is correct and did fix my problem, as I was getting a `NullReferenceException` error.

However, while I was trying to fix it myself I learnt how to correctly bind the `Slider`'s Value to the `TextBox`'s Width property like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="MainTextArea" 
         Margin="0,71" 
         BorderThickness="0" 
         Background="{x:Null}" 
         BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
         SelectionHighlightColor="#FF444444" 
         Foreground="White" 
         Canvas.ZIndex="1" 
         TabIndex="1" 
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
         Padding="0" 
         FontSize="18" 
         FontFamily="Georgia" 
         IsSpellCheckEnabled="False" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
         RequestedTheme="Dark" 
         Width="{Binding Value, ElementName=TextBoxSizeSlider}"   
         TextChanged="MainTextArea_TextChanged" 
         TextWrapping="Wrap" 
         AcceptsReturn="True" 
         PlaceholderText="" Loaded="MainTextArea_Loaded" />
```

Note how the width is bound to the `Slider`'s Value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Textbox is null because it hasn't loaded yet.

```
    private void Slider_OnValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextBox != null)
        {
            TextBox.Width = e.NewValue;
        }
    }
```

*If textbox loads after the slider value changes it will miss the initial value*

```
    private void TextBox_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Slider != null)
        {
            TextBox.Width = Slider.Value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Although the correct events name should be called: `Slider_ValueChanged (...) and TextBox.Loaded(...)

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be setting the width of the `TextBox` on the slider `valueChanged` event, then why don't you do it directly in the event handler?

```
private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox.Width = e.newValue;
}
```

You can then just set the default value of 1000 in XAML. No bindings needed?

EDIT:

About the `NullReferenceException`, check out this question: [WPF Slider control (NullReferenceException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611130/wpf-slider-control-nullreferenceexception)

It notes that as soon as the slider is created it will raise a `ValueChanged` event, which has the potential to cause problems depending on the order of your XAML.

It mentions the simplest fix is to catch the null object in the `ValueChanged` event, but a better alternative is to bind the values together in XAML (as opposed to in the code behind).

Comment: It does not work, I get this NullReferenceException occurred with the following text for that particular line:
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in (App name)

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.


I previously tried the same approach with a simpler line, like:
textBox.Width = slider.Value;

But I was getting the same thing.

Comment: are you checking if textBox is null?
Your slider is loading before the textbox. 
When the UI is loading the slider value may be set before the textbox has loaded. If that's the case, create an event handler for TextBox.Loaded="your event handler" and setting the value there too.

Comment: @BryanStump, I tried doing something, but it still gets stuck at the Value Changed event.

See Edit for code.

Comment: Why do you need to set the width of the `TextBox` when the page loads?  You haven't said that the value can vary before the user can manipulate the slider, so by default it will just be the length you set in XAML (which I would assume you've set as the default value of the `Slider`? Alternatively, if you really want to set the width on page load, do it after `InitialiseComponent` in the page constructor.

Comment: @J.B I don't get what you mean. I'm not setting it when the page loads, as you have already suggested.
The Width default value is set to 1100. 
The Slider value is set to 1100 too from XAML.

Now, as I tried explaining, I want to change the `TextBox` width by using the `Slider`. Leaving aside the binding approach I tried and using your suggestion, if I try to change the width from the `Slider`'s ValueChanged event, I get the  'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in (App name) Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error I previously mentioned.